# Visual SVN Checkout error

Tags: eclipse, svn, svn-checkout

I got a `error` while checking out the project from visual svn repository in eclipse IDE please check the error.

> Checkout operation for 'https://Server07:8443/svn/sample/branches/Version 1.0.231-05-2016/TEMP01' failed.
>   svn: E204899: Cannot rename file 'D:\Workspace\TEMP01.svn\svn.7bb52562-5501-0010-af0c-7bf60e37ee36.tmp' to 'D:\Worksapce\TEMP01.svn\pristine\5e\5e50d2833134bb061939d97df46f32fd12c64d50.svn-base'

Please help me out to resolve the above `issue`.

Answer (score 0):

Try kill the windows explorer from the Windows Task Manager, then checkout your project. If this works, restart your explorer.exe

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the .svn folder and try again. I have noticed this happens sometimes when checkout stops in between.